# ParseException: Unparseable date: "04 December"

Tags: scala, parsing, date

I have the birthday date `04 December` I want to save it as `04-12` in the database, for that I do this:

```
val birthday = theForm.field("birthday") //String
val date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(birthday)
```

But i get the error: `ParseException: Unparseable date: "04 December"`

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your date format string is not correct.  Try it as "dd MMMM".  The javadocs for `SimpleDateFormat` are pretty comprehensive for format possibilities:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

It seems like you want to parse it as one format and then re-format it into another.  For this you can use two separate `SimpleDateFormat` instances, one with "dd MMMM" for parsing the `04 December` format and one with "dd-MM" for re-formatting into the format you want to save to your db.  The code would look like this:

```
val date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(birthday)
val dbDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date)
```

Comment: Like this: 
val date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(birthday)
val date2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date) 
?

Comment: Then i get this error: type mismatch; found : java.util.Date required: String

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import java.time._

val  birthDay = MonthDay.parse("--12-04")
```